# Until-Successful Process for list of objects in a long running query not working

Tags: mule, mule-component

I want to develop a flow that could allow me to make queries to an external system that could take a long time to return. I may have to make queries for multiple values in a list.  I am using an until-successful scope in solving the problem. Unfortunately, the even though the request is run several times, the failed records never get put in the dead letter queue. Here is my attempt at solving the problem:

```
    <!-- Dead Letter Queue for exhausted attempts-->
    <vm:endpoint name="DLQ" path="DLQ_VM" doc:name="VM"/>

    <flow name="StartFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <!--Place a list of String errors to query for on this vm -->
         <vm:inbound-endpoint path="request-processing-queue" " 
                        exchange-pattern="one-way" doc:name="VM"/>
          <vm:outbound-endpoint path="reprocessing-queue" 
                        exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="VM"/>
          <logger level="INFO" message="Data returned is #[payload]"/>
          <catch-exception-strategy>
             <logger level="ERROR"  message="Failure During Processing"/>
           </catch-exception-strategy>
    </flow>



   <flow name="RetryingProcess">
       <vm:inbound-endpoint name="reprocessing-vm" exchange-
                                               pattern="request-response" 
                                path="reprocessing-queue" doc:name="VM"/>
       <foreach collection="#[payload]" doc:name="For Each">
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="by-singles-vm"  exchange-
                            pattern="request-response"/>
       </foreach>
   </flow>


        <flow name="query-retry">
          <vm:inbound-endpoint path="by-singles-vm" exchange-
    pattern="request-response" doc:name="VM"/>
          <until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore"
                      failureExpression="#[groovy:(exception &amp;&amp; 
                 exception in com.trion.CustomException)
                                         ||!(payload instanceof 
                  com.trion.QueryResult])]"
                      maxRetries="5"
                      millisBetweenRetries="300000"
                      deadLetterQueue-ref="DLQ_VM" doc:name="Until 
                                                      Successful">
                  <vm:outbound-endpoint path="try-again-vm" exchange-
            pattern="request-response" doc:name="VM"/>
          </until-successful>
        </flow>
    <flow name="GetQueryValue" >
           <vm:inbound-endpoint path="try-again-vm" exchange-
           pattern="request-response" doc:name="VM"/>
           <flow-ref name="QueryRequest" />
    </flow>

 <!-- This never happens, i.e. the results are not put here... after retying 
                         -->
   <flow name="AttemptsExceededProcessing">
    <inbound-endpoint ref="DLQ_VM" doc:name="Generic"/>
    <logger level="DEBUG" message="Entering Final Destination Queue with 
       payload is #[payload]"/>
   </flow>

    <!-- Here I have a query to the external system... >
    <flow name="QueryRequest">
      ...... Makes the long running query Here..
     //returns com.trion.QueryResult
      </flow>
  </mule>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem with the configuration. I had a millisSecondsBetweenRetry value set so small I wasn't seeing the log messages and assumed it wasn't working.